# Inner section in a full width section not wider than the content width

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a full width section with two columns. The split is 2/3 and 1/3. In the left column, I have added an Inner Section. I would like this inner section to be no wider to the left than the content width. Does anyone know a simple solution for this?

[image: Image of expected result]